# How do I migrate the tables from my existing MySQL server to a new one?

Tags: linux, mysql, migration

I know exactly how to move the users from one server to another, but I'm not too sure about how to move the tables that I already have along with it.

FYI this is a Kaltura server so I need to be extremely careful about it, no "oops" allowed.

How do I to move my MySQL server to another computer?

Comment: Check the official MySQL documentation for mysqldump. It's tool #1 for doing simple backup/restores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `mysqldump` from your existing server and import it on the new server.

`man mysqldump` should give examples of the various syntax options available. [The mysql.com page for it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) has plenty of useful info as well.

This will leave all of your data right where it is, just in case there is an "oops", you can quickly roll back to using your old server.